# Add multiple curves / functions to one ggplot through looping

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add multiple curves to one `ggplot`. With the normal `plot` and `curve(add=TRUE)` i can loop the curve function and can add multiple curves/functions.

Since i want to rewrite my code for `ggplot`, i'm trying to figure out how achieve this with ggplot.

I'm using the `stat_function` and a `for` loop, but `ggplot` is not adding the `curve`, just saving the last one.

Minimum reproducible example with a single line:

```
library(ggplot2)
p1<-ggplot()
for (i in 1:10){
  p1<- p1 + stat_function(aes(x=1:200),fun = function(x) {x+i*3}, col=i)
  print(p1)
}
```

What i think the code should do:

I loop multiple `stat_function` and adding it to my plot `p1`

What i want to do:

I want alle lines to be added in one plot(`p1`). The code as it is, just shows the last line of the loop, as if it is overwriting the plot always, but as far as i understand `ggplot` this should just add a line. Also an explanation why this does not work would be nice, maybe i just don't understand `ggplot` here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that all the `stat_function`s you are refer to the *same* `i` variable. And as a consequence, each function you add will overlay perfectly with the others.

The solution is to reassign the variable in a local scope, to make a local copy for each iteration:

```
p1 = ggplot(data.frame(x = 1 : 200)) + aes(x)

for (i in 1:10){
    p1 = local({
        j = i
        p1 + stat_function(fun = function(x) x + j * 3, col = j)
    })
}
```

To make matters more confusing, you don’t actually have to give the local variable a new name; you could just as easily have written `i = i`, and continued to use `i`. The reason is that this assignment will generate a *new local variable `i`* that masks the non-local variable `i`. I hope we can agree that writing such code is confusing, and a bad idea.

I’ve also taken the liberty of simplifying your code slightly by moving the data `x` out of the `stat_function`, and into the `ggplot` object directly.

**However**, it is altogether cleaner not to use a loop and reassignment here. Instead you can use `lapply` or `map` (from the purrr package):

```
p1 = ggplot(data.frame(x = 1 : 200)) +
    aes(x) +
    map(
        1 : 10,
        ~ stat_function(fun = function (x) x + .x * 3, color = .x)
    )
```

This is shorter, more readable (it focuses on the “what” rather than the “how”, i.e. the mechanics of the loop), and it uses a single assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
library(ggplot2)
add_curve <- function(plot, i) {
  return(plot + stat_function(aes(x=1:200),fun = function(x) {x+i*3}, col=i))
}

p1 <- ggplot()


for (i in 1:10){
  p1<- add_curve(p1, i)
}

p1
```

Output is:

[image]

Or alternatively you can also define your function inside the for-loop:

```
for (i in 1:10){
  add_curve <- function(plot, i) {
    return(plot + stat_function(aes(x=1:200),fun = function(x) {x+i*3}, col=i))
  }
  p1<- add_curve(p1, i)
}
```

Or as a (somewhat obscure) `Reduce` + `lapply` one-liner (thx to @KonradRudolph):

```
eval(
  Reduce(function(a, b) call('+', a, b), 
         lapply(1:10, function(i) {
           bquote(stat_function(aes(x=1:200),fun = function(x) {x+.(i)*3
             }, col=.(i)))}), init = quote(ggplot())))
```

The idea is to build the whole `ggplot()` call at once and then evaluate it.

Comment: Rather than using `parse` with string `paste`ing, you can manipulate the unevaluated expressions — the `bquote` approach goes in the right direction. To combine expressions into a summation, you can use `Reduce`. The general approach would be: `Reduce(function (a, b) call('+', a, b), lapply(1 : 10, ‹FUN›, init = quote(ggplot()))`, where ‹FUN› is a function that builds a `stat_function` call expression (similar to what you have, without the prefix `+`). That said, the result is still unnecessarily convoluted, since ggplot() allows adding a list of plot elements (see my answer), no need for eval

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Thx for pointing me to this. I somewhat hoped you would react to my attempt of providing an `lapply` solution, since I just started learning about how to tinker with expressions.. ;-)